# Int array fills with last int

Tags: java, arrays, int

I'm trying to fill an int array with integers. However, when I print out the array, I just get the same last value repeating 25 times, which is not what I want. I want to populate the array with the different ints that I get from the Bluetooth service...

```
weightFromDevice = intent.getExtras().getInt(BluetoothService.MESSAGE_WEIGHT_DATA); //take int values from bluetooth service

int [] _weightCount = new int[25]; // Array has a length of 25
Arrays.fill(_weightCount, weightFromDevice); //Trying to fill array with the different ints

String res = Arrays.toString(_weightCount); //Array to string for printing

displayData(res); // calling method to print array
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have only one `int` why do you think you have 25 different ints?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and inspecting the state of your program?

Comment: Print weightFromDevice. Where is the declaration of this variable anyway?

Comment: @MuratK.the Bluetooth service broadcasts 25 ints in another class. I use the ints to calculate an average, so I know it works. I just can't seem to get my array to work...

Comment: That's what fill is for: fill an array with the same value

Comment: @MauricePerry So I can't fill the array with different values?

Comment: @cashmoneyscience You can, but not with Arrays.fill

Comment: I appreciate the super-quick accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)) for `fill()`:

> Assigns the specified int value to each element of the specified array of ints.

Your code fetches **one** int value and then uses a method that puts that one value into each slot of the given array.

When you want **different** values to be in there:

- write a loop
- within the loop: fetch one value and assign it to the "next" slot

Like:

```
int [] weightCount = new int[numElements];
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
  weightCount[i] = intent.getExtras().getInt(BluetoothService.MESSAGE_WEIGHT_DATA); //take int values from bluetooth service
}
```

Comment: My guess, because your initial answer was essentially a link only answer, and was way too vague if the link broke. (it is still a little vague though, not explicitly saying you are referring to Arrays.fill) I'd just suggest edits for that though.

Comment: I don't know the relation of downvotes to edits, but a quote without context can be quite confusing sometimes. Redundancy usually makes better clarity. People are VERY fast to downvote, so it helps if initial post is good enough to stand on its own. That is just my educated guess as to why though.

Answer (score 1):

To add something to @GhostCat answer, this is the code of fill method:

```
/**
  * Assigns the specified int value to each element of the specified array
  * of ints.
  *
  * @param a the array to be filled
  * @param val the value to be stored in all elements of the array
  */
  public static void fill(int[] a, int val) {
        for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
             a[i] = val;
  }
```

You used the wrong method